# Загрузка апплета

Tags: установка, setup, java, applet

Установила яву 8, теперь в браузере апплет не открывается, что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, это связано с настройками безопасности Java. Откройте контрольную панель Java (Java Control Panel). Перейдите на вкладку Безопасность (Security). Добавьте нужный вам сайт в список исключений (кнопка Edit Site List).